# iPhone: Strange leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Ok the below problem is solved but now its creating leak for this block

```
NSMutableArray *tempRowArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempRowArray addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]];
    [pickerList addObject:tempRowArray];
    [tempRowArray release];
```

for tempRowArray

ahh I am lost in this memory problems.

Solved:
Hi,

Can you please help me in this, I have following condition

1) Declared an array in `.h` file.
2) Created property and synthesized it
3) In `viewWillAppear` allocated memory to it

```
pickerList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

4) Read data from database and stored objects in this array

```
if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        NSMutableArray *tempRowArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [tempRowArray addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]];
        [pickerList addObject:tempRowArray];
        [tempRowArray release];
    }
}
```

picker list is shown as memory leak out there
and application eventually crashes after some time please help me get rid of it

5) I have released *pickerList* in `dealloc()` and set it to nil in `viewDidUnload`

Comment: When you set it to nil in viewDidUnload, are you using self.pickerList = nil;? That is different from pickerList = nil;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time the view appears you allocate `pickerList`. Allocate it in `viewDidLoad` and then release it in `viewDidUnload`.

Answer (score 2):

In `viewWillAppear` you are allocating memory. In case of you are switching to and from this view controller, your `viewWillAppear` will be getting called and you would be allocating memory again and again.

Do it in `viewDidLoad` and also use its property while allocating it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the synthesized setter method to set the array in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.pickerList=[NSMutableArray array];
```

And set it to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`

```
self.pickerList = nil;
```

The reason you are getting a leak is because you are probably calling `pickerList = nil` in `viewDidUnload`

There is a difference between `pickerList = something` and `self.pickerList = something`. In the first instance you are setting the value directly, but if you use the second version (and you have declared `@property (retain) NSMutableArray *pickerList` the @synthesized setter method will retain the new value and release the old value.

In your case, by just setting it to nil in `viewDidUnload` you lose the pointer to the original object, so you can't release it, and you have a leak.

Comment: This isn't the source of the leak. This is a style choice.

Comment: @PengOne True - but this way when the view loads it will release the previously allocated mutable array and replace it with a new one. Which stops the leak.

Comment: @Abizern Touche. It might be nice to add that explanation to your answer so that he (and future generations) understand the source of the leak and how this plugs it.

Comment: Abizem is right. His statement when placed in view will appear will not leak. But there is no need to allocated again and again. View did load is a better place.

Comment: @PengOne, @Abizern, So this answer deserves a +1.

Comment: @PengOne - Well, it's there now! :)

Comment: @Abizern: Oh come on, add it to the answer and I'll up vote you ;-)

Comment: @PengOne, @Abizern, I've already up voted believing he'd add that to the answer soon :-)

Comment: @Abizern, @Simon, Don't worry, I'm withholding until compliance ;-)

Comment: @all - Is this detailed enough for you? :)

Comment: The fundamentals you specified regarding view did unload is correct. But view did unload doesnt necessarily gets called always. It does during low memory issues, when the controller unloads its view to free up memory. We dont know actually if thats the case here.

Comment: Yes, but even if it doesn't get released there, it will get released next time the view loads.

Comment: @Abizern, Yes, Its enough :-)

Comment: Yes, i agree with that :). Lets bail out from here :-)